# Erf function discrepancy

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I have very strange problem involving $\operatorname{erf}$ functions:

```
f1[r_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-(ky/(2 Sqrt[π])- (r[[1]] + I r[[2]]) Sqrt[π])^2], {ky, -π, π}];

f2[r_] := N[(Erf[(r[[1]] + I r[[2]]) π - Sqrt[π]/2,(r[[1]] + I r[[2]]) π + Sqrt[π]/2]), 3];

f3[r_] := N[π (-Erf[1/2 Sqrt[π] (-1 + 2 (r[[1]] + I r[[2]]))] +
               Erf[1/2 Sqrt[π] (1 + 2 (r[[1]] + I r[[2]]))]), 3];

f4[r_] := N[π Erf[1/2 Sqrt[π] (-1 + 2 (r[[1]] + I r[[2]])),
                  1/2 Sqrt[π] (1 + 2 (r[[1]] + I r[[2]]))], 3]
```

When I evaluate these functions, I get these results:

```
f1[{0, -4.4}]
4.90038*10^25 + 1.28849*10^11 I

f2[{0, -4.4 }]
-2.29748*10^81 + 0. I

f3[{0, -4.4}]
4.90038*10^25 + 0. I

f4[{0, -4.4}]
4.90038*10^25 + 0. I
```

The real part is same for numerical integration and `Erf[p, q]` function, but the imaginary part is way off. Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: How odd. `With[{t = -4.4 I}, NIntegrate[Exp[-(ky/(2 Sqrt[π]) - t Sqrt[π])^2], {ky, -π, π}]]` gives a real answer, but `NIntegrate[Exp[-(ky/(2 Sqrt[π]) - (-4.4 I) Sqrt[π])^2], {ky, -π, π}]` does not.

Comment: I've even tried to find the series expansion for erf function and then plug in values but it did not help either.

Comment: Personally, I'm more inclined to rely on the result of two-argument `Erf[]`. Is there any reason why you need to use `NIntegrate[]`?

Comment: This is appearing in my condensed matter physics research. `NIntegrate` is consequence of doing approximation from summation over momentum space to the integration over momentum space in thermodynamic limit. The results obtained from `NIntegrate[]` and summation are in a agreement  so I know that `NIntegrate[]` is giving valid results, valid in a sense that probability distribution is finite. If I do `Erf[]` difference result the probability distribution diverges so the results are not physically valid.

Comment: The problem you presented here, and the problem you describe in your last comment, are seemingly at odds. In your post, it's the third and fourth functions that are sensible, and the first one with `NIntegrate[]` that is broken.

Comment: Sorry my bad, the expression I've posted is just part of wave function, I need to take `Abs[]^2` in order to get probability distribution. So complex wave function is ok.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're just seeing numerical noise with the [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) function. Notice that the imaginary part is close to 15 orders of magnitude smaller than the real part:

```
Normalize[4.90038*10^25 + 1.28849*10^11 I]
```

> `1. + 2.62937*10^-15 I`

Typically, you can use extended precision numbers to avoid this complex fuzz:

```
f1[r_] := NIntegrate[
    Exp[-(ky/(2 Sqrt[π])-(r[[1]]+I r[[2]]) Sqrt[π])^2],
    {ky, -π, π},
    WorkingPrecision -> 30
]

f1[{0, -4.4`30}]
```

> 4.90038260934708012885614518740*10^25

Answer (score 1):

One way to get rid of machine-precision rounding noise is to use a relative-error `Chop` with a small multiple of `$MachineEpsilon`:

```
relChop[z_?NumericQ, e_: 10 $MachineEpsilon] := Chop[z/Abs[z], e] Abs[z]

relChop[f1[{0, -4.4}]]
(*  4.90038*10^25  *)
```